# How to delete rows with ONLY a CRLF?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Yesterday my code worked fine and today it doesn't work.  Very bizarre.  I'm trying to loop through lines in a file and delete all lines with ONLY a CRLF or ONLY '#' (without the quotes).

```
with open('C:\\my_path\\AllData.txt') as oldfile, open('C:\\Users\\my_path\\AllDataFinal.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        # within for loop
        line = "" if line.rstrip() in line else line
        line = "" if "#" in line else line
        newfile.write(line)
print('DONE!!')
```

In the screen shot below, I want to delete the first line, and the second line, but not the third line.

[image]

I tried a few combination of things like `rstrip()` and `rstrip('\n')`.  Every time now, I am left with a blank file.

Comment: `line.rstrip() in line` is always true - `.rstrip()` returns a substring of its input, `in` checks for substrings.  `not line.rstrip()` would be a suitable condition to detect lines consisting entirely of whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Every time now, I am left with a blank file". That is because `line.rstrip()` is always in `line`. I prefer working with plain old strings from the begining.

```
# File -> string
s_old = open('test1.py').read()
s_new = ''
for line in s_old.splitlines():
    if not line.startswith("#") and line.strip():                                      
        s_new += line
# String -> file
open('test2.py', 'w').write(s_new)
```

Note that `'#' in line` is not the same as `line.startswith('#')`. And `line.strip()` is returning the line with the newline(s) character(s) at the end so if the line is empty, that is an empty string evaluating to false.

Comment: Oh, this actually does work the way I was hoping it would.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: The pleasure is mine. By the way, for doing it in excel macro, yes python is not suited for that. I would use vim macro too. But the "canonical" way of doing this king of easy stuff is with regex like `cat test1.py | sed -e '/^\(#\|$\)/d'` in bash.sed. Then you can use `re` module in python

Answer (score 1):

I've made some modifications to your script. I'm just using a plain old `replace()` for all the `\r\n` and does a check if the cleaned line is empty;

```
with open('test.txt') as oldfile, open('test_cleaned.txt', 'w') as newfile:
    for line in oldfile:
        # within for loop
        cleaned_line = line.replace("\r\n", "")
        if cleaned_line == '#' or cleaned_line == '':
          # Ignore the lines that are blank or are just #
          continue
        newfile.write(cleaned_line + "\n")
print('DONE!!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable "line" name to (its conflicting)

```
line1 = "" if line.rstrip() in line else line
line2 = "" if "#" in line else line
newfile.write(line1)
newfile.write(line2)
```

Comment: Lol.  I didn't realize it was doing that.  Ok, that makes sense now.  I tried to simplify the code a bit, but got an empty file once again:

line1 = "" if line.rstrip() or "#" in line else line1
        newfile.write(line1)

Comment: Actually, none of these things is working.  Either lines repeat, so I have all dupes for everything, or the blank lines are NOT removed.  I have to switch over to Excel.  I can do this in 5 seconds in Excel.